# androidx navigation api: can we make the menu button always visible?

Tags: android

I have an app that uses the androidx navigation api. it works as expected. but i don't understand why the menu button would change from the hamburger icon to the up arrow, since we have a global one available to us. So, I was wondering if it was possible to force the api to keep the hamburger button at all times. I have found that if you use the following code;

```
val navSet = setOf(R.id.nav_journal, R.id.nav_copyright)
val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navSet, drawerLayout)
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
navController = navHostFragment.navController
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

then the hamburger icon will appear for both activities but it seems unwieldy to maintain a list of possible navigation activities.

Comment: What do you mean by "global one available to us"? Are you using Single Activity pattern with multiple Fragments? If so, that's the normal behavior. "Up" button behaves the same as "Back" button.

Comment: @SamChen the global back button. next to the home button. I realise that it is normal behaviour, but i wish for the hamburger menu button to be there all the time, instead of the up button.

Comment: You mean you want the "Up" button shows Hamburger icon instead of arrorw even you are in the second or third `Fragment` (or deeper page of your app)? If so, it will confuse user, because we all know Hamburger icon will show drawer when click, and back arrow icon will take us back to prevous screen.

Comment: @SamChen Yes, I would expect that the hamburger will still open the drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, _ ->       
    if (destination.id == R.id.xxx || destination.id == R.id.xxx || ... ) {
        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger)
    }
}
```

- Find **Hamburger** icon here: https://materialdesignicons.com/

---

And add this to each of your other `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        requireActivity().drawerLayout.open()
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I removed the If. since I don't want to have to populate every activity/fragment I use. However, the functionality doesn't change, if the hamburger icon would open the drawer each time, that would be perfect.

Comment: @glend As you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `setOpenableLayout()` to attach the `drawerLayout` into the `appBarConfiguration`

This requires to use `AppBarConfiguration.Builder` pattern:

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
    R.id.nav_journal, R.id.nav_copyright
).setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout).build()

val navHostFragment =
    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController: NavController = navHostFragment.navController
setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

Also make sure you add all the fragments that you don't want to show the up/back button in, into the `appBarConfiguration`. You already added a couple of them (`R.id.nav_journal, R.id.nav_copyright`), if you have more fragments in the drawer, then you need to add them as well.